# How to output a csv file every minute while running a code on an indefinite time frame?

Tags: selenium, csv, scrapy, livechat

I try to crawl a live chat on this webpage on the right side: https://www.galaxus.ch/de/wiki/2736
What code do I need to run in order to create a csv file every minute?
Currently, it is getting created at the end of the script. However, if it's indefinite, it will never get created.

Thank you for the tips

Comment: Not sure whether you can easily create a csv every minute, but you can batch your output with [FEED_EXPORT_BATCH_ITEM_COUNT](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-export-batch-item-count)

Comment: You need to put your "writing part" into your loop, so the data gets immediately written, as soon as you saved it like @tomjn said into your export_fields :) your method currently loads all data into your ram and creates csv-file after script is done.

If you can provide a short code snippet, I think we can get this done